# Garbage Collection of Spring Beans

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

How the the objects managed by spring are garbage collected? Java garbage collector can find the normal objects (I mean I have not injected them via dependency injection).

How does the garbage collector collect spring beans? Since it cannot track them via stack. I would like the gc to garbage collect the spring beans that not being used.

Comment: "My" garbage collector?  That's the JVM's job.  You shouldn't collect anything.  The Spring bean factory manages the beans.  All of this is Java, so it proceeds under the control of the JVM according to Java's rules.

Comment: I meant to say like if I work on JVM development, how I would manage it. I have updated the question now to not create the confusion.

Comment: JVM development?  You aren't writing a JVM, are you?  Spring is doing it properly.  You shouldn't be bothering about it.  Better to understand the life cycle of Spring beans and understand how it interacts with the JVM and the GC.  I do not understand your repeated references to the stack trace.  That doesn't have anything to do with garbage collection or memory management.  This question makes no sense at all.

Comment: How spring handles it? I just want to know how it is handled. I was asked this question during an interview. I was unable to think about it. So I am asking it here.

Comment: You aren't getting that job if you keep thinking that stack traces have anything to do with garbage collection.  Go learn Java.

Comment: There's nothing to handle. The JVM is responsible to collect garbage. Not you. Not Spring. Spring beans are not special objects that need to be taken care of differently from any other Java object, regarding GC.

Comment: Spring beans are POJOs, just like your "normal" objects.  There is no difference. The live on the heap and are managed by the JVM garbage collector.  All Spring has done is given you a well-written, configurable object factory for managing dependency injection.

Comment: I was asked if I had to work in  development of a garbage collector in a JVM, how would I make it? I answered I will track the objects via stack of call to know the active objects so this was an added question to that, how will I garbage collect spring objects. And yes I am learning java and I will go and learn more. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: The Java GC doesn't care about stacks of calls. It cares about static variables referencing objects, and threads containing references to objects in their stack. If an object is reachable through a chain of strong references from any of those root references, then the object is not a candidate for GC. All the others are. Spring beans are no different.

Comment: Start with the basics.   This question is too broad for SO.  You won't learn how to do it here.   https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/

Answer (score 0):

The beans instantiated by Spring are not in "your" stack, as in they are not variables you have manually created, but they are in the Spring IOC stack which manages its lifecycle, and it is holding reference to locate all those beans, ergo, they are referenced and their "stack" is alive while the application is up.

Spring is keeping all your beans referenced in a SingletonBeanRegistry which hold maps of your beans and different ways to access them, so as they are referenced there, usually the GC will not dispose of them.