# Spring Boot read application.properties / .yml variable without annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a class using new operator and in that class I want to read a property from application.yml file, how to do that in Spring Boot application ?

In other words I cannot use @Value, @Autowire, @Component annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class TestProperties{
    private String testProperty1;

    public String getTestProperty1() {
        return testProperty1;
    }
    public void setTestProperty1(String testProperty1) {
        this.testProperty1= testProperty1;
    }
}
```

next in Your application.properties:

```
test.testPropety1 = yourProperty
```

You can implement this properties class as bean because of @Configuration annotation. Hope that helps in Your problem :)

Comment: So when I will do in some method TestProperties t = new TestProperties() I will have t.testPropety1 filled ? And will that t variable be garbage collected after my method ends ?

Comment: You pass this class in constructor. Then You will have all properties filled with data from application.properties. But as I remember "new" keyword works as well too.

Comment: and yes, when You use it in class without constructor or "new" keyword it will be null.

Comment: here You have informations about JVM GC with Spring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757225/garbage-collection-of-spring-beans